# Find a sequence of function in the Schwartz space $S(\mathbb R)$ which does not converge in $S(\mathbb R)$

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Show there exists a sequence $\{f_n\}$ in the Schwartz space $S(\mathbb R)$ with limit $f$ for which 
$$
\lim \|f_n\|_{u,v} \text{ induced that } f \not\in S(\mathbb R) \text{ for some } u,v. 
$$
But 
$$
\lim \|f_n\|_{a,b} \text{ does not converges when } a \ne u,b\ne v.
$$
Use the standard norm on $S(\mathbb R)$
$$
\|f\|_{a,b}= \sup_{x \in \mathbb R} |x^af^{(b)}(x)| ,\, a,b \in \mathbb Z_+.
$$

This [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/145796/14108) shows $\sqrt{f(x)}$ does not belongs to $S(\mathbb R)$ when $f(x)=e^{-x^2} \left(e^{-x^2}+\sin ^2(x)\right)$.
I guess one way is to make $\|f_n\|_{u,v}$ unbounded, while keeping the other derivative bounded.
But I don't see how to do that.

Comment: It $\{f_n\}$ which have to converge to $f$ in $\lVert\cdot\rVert_{u,v}$, not the sequence of norms.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo I meant what you said, but didn't express it well. Thank you.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo I adjusted the question, to reflect your point. Thank you.

Comment: What does "induced" mean here?

Comment: @joriki I meant that $\lim \|f_n\|_{u,v}$ breaks the rule for $f$ to be $S$, that is $\lim \|f\|_{u,v}=\infty$.   
I think the question highlight the completeness of $S$, with respect to its topology.  
As  $\lim \|f\|_{u,v}=\infty$ should implies that $\{f_n\} \subset S$ does not converges in $S$.  
Whence, the other limits, $\lim\|f_n\|_{a,b}$, should not exist.