# Give an example a function sequence in the Schwartz space $\mathcal S(\Bbb R)$ which does not converge

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

Give an example of a function sequence in the Schwartz space $\mathcal S(\Bbb R)$ which does not converge.
That is, for any $a,b \in \Bbb Z_+$, 
$$
\|f_n\|_{a,b} < \infty,
$$
but
$$
\|f\|_{u,v}=\infty,
$$
for some $u,v \in \Bbb Z_+$, when $\{f_n\} \subset \mathcal S$ converges to $f$ pointwise, that is
$$
\lim_n f_n(x)=f(x), \forall x \in \Bbb R.
$$
Use the standard $\mathcal S$-norms
$$
\|f\|_{a,b}=\sup_{x \in \Bbb R} \left| x^a f^{(b)}(x) \right|, \, a,b \in \Bbb Z_+.
$$

The following function does not belongs to $\mathcal S$
\begin{align}
f(x)&=e^{-x^2}sin\left(e^{x^2}\right), \\
f(x)&=\frac{1}{1+x^2}.
\end{align}
But I don't see how to make an $\mathcal S$-sequence converging to them pointwise.

This question arised when considering this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/228129/14108).

Comment: I think you should clarify which mode of convergence is involved in your question. For example, if the convergence is induced by the $\mathcal{S}$-norms, then $f$ also lie in $\mathcal{S}$ (since the Schwartz space is a Fréchet-Montel space.)

Comment: @sos440 Good point. I choosed pointwise convergence of $f_n$ to $f$.

Comment: Then how about a sequence of Gaussian kernels? For example $$ f_n(x) = \exp\left( -\frac{x^2}{n} \right) $$ is a sequence of Schwartz functions while converging to $1$ pointeise.

Comment: @sos440 A perfectly fine example. Thank you.

Comment: @sos440 Your can post your comment as an answer.